# How to call variables from initialize script from Yaml config file

Tags: configuration, initialization, yaml, erb

I'm trying to run an initialize script to help me with retrieving data from my config.yml file.

config.yml currently looks like this:

```
production: &default
  log_server: log_server
  deploy_to: /path/to/deploy
  unicorn:
    port: 8080
    uid: user 
    gid: group
 development: &dev
  <<: *default
  deploy_to:path/to/deploy
  unicorn:
    port: 80
    uid: unicorn 
    gid: unicorngroup
```

Here's the config.rb file that I have so far:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'erb'

config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("/Users/NguyenC/gomoto_server/config/api_settings.yml")).result)
```

If I 'puts config', the output looks like this:

```
{"production"=>{"log_server"=>"log_server", "deploy_to"=>"path/to/deploy",  "unicorn"=>{"port"=>8080, "uid"=>"user", "gid"=>"group"}}, "development"=>{"log_server"=>"log_server", "deploy_to"=>"path/to/deploy", "unicorn"=>{"port"=>80, "uid"=>"unicorn", "gid"=>"unicorn group"}}
```

How then would I call the variables if I wanted to only get certain ones from either prod or development?  My goal is to be able to call any variable depending on the Env that I use.